# Como meto estos dos string en un jpanel

Tags: java

Aqui no me da error, pero quiero añadir dat junto a arr:

```
public void guardarDatos(int l,int c, String arr,String dat){
        if(c<=4){
        jp3.remove(ju[c]);
        }
        ju[c+5] = new JLabel((String) arr);
        ju[c+5].setBounds(20, l, 450, 30);
        jp3.add(ju[c+5]);
    }
```

Aquí ya me da error, no se como debería poner

```
public void guardarDatos(int l,int c, String arr,String dat){
        if(c<=4){
        jp3.remove(ju[c]);
        }
        ju[c+5] = new JLabel((String) arr, (String) dat);
        ju[c+5].setBounds(20, l, 450, 30);
        jp3.add(ju[c+5]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ser los dos de tipo String lo unico que debes es concatenar, sustituye la linea

```
ju[c+5] = new JLabel((String) arr, (String) dat);
```

por

```
ju[c+5] = new JLabel(arr+" "+dat);
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, creo que funciono, esperemos que con esto no encuentre otros errores

Comment: Disculpa, por si acaso te puedo contactar para una consulta?